# THREE.js Mesh is not filling BoxHelper

Tags: 3d, three.js

I'm not sure how to get my `THREE.Mesh` to cover all six sides of my `THREE.BoxHelper`. For some reason only three triangles are appearing on three of the sides. It seems to be using only 8 vertices. How do I connect all of the vertices? The larger outlined black box is a `THREE.BoxHelper` on it's own without any `THREE.Mesh` added. (The `object` below is a `THREE.OBJLoader` that I simply want the box outline of). Thank you in advance for any insight!

```js
let box = new THREE.BoxHelper(object, 0xff0000);
let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(box.geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

[Animated GIF of the BoxHelper with three triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mCCy.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometry of `THREE.BoxHelper` is intended for `THREE.LineSegments`. You are trying to render with this geometry a `THREE.Mesh`. Since both objects use different primitives for rendering (`LINES` vs.`TRIANGLES`), you don't get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I suppose the question then is how can I get the `THREE.BoxGeometry` (along with world positioning) from a bounding box created with `THREE.Box3`? Positioning seems to be the main problem. It looks like I can create the box geometry with a `getSize()` call on the `THREE.Box3`, but I can't get the `THREE.Mesh` to show up in the same place as the `THREE.Box3`. I'm using `mesh.position.copy(box.matrixWorld.getPosition());`.

Comment: It might not be the best solution, but I think I figured out what I needed. Using the `THREE.Box3` min/max values I am setting the position with `mesh.position.set(box.min.x + ((box.max.x - box.min.x) / 2), box.min.y + ((box.max.y - box.min.y) / 2), box.min.z + ((box.max.z - box.min.z) / 2);`